# SendMessage working only with MessageBox in C#

Tags: c#, messagebox, sendmessage

I've a strange problem with my application in C#.

I've a function call `setYellow()` and in another application, i've got a control with 5 colors.

The coordinates for colors are: red 20, yellow 40, green 60, blue 80, purple 100 (in that control).

So i'm using SendMessage to click the colors, in this way:

```
PostMessage(colori.hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, MakeLParam(40, 9));
PostMessage(colori.hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 1, MakeLParam(40, 9));
```

I've now list of commands sent by users through a console with buttons, and one of this invokes the `setYellow()` function.

Now, if I create a button that invokes `setYellow()`, it works fine!
If I read the command from list, it invokes `setYellow()` and clicks the right coordinate, but the application click on the RED button...

If I see with Spy++, it sends the right coordinate and if I see the differences between `setYellow` from button, and `setYellow` from command list, there is NO DIFFERENCE!

But wait, the magic... if I put a:

```
MessageBox.Show("BYE");
```

before the PostMessage, it works from command list too!!!

I tried to slow my application with `Thread.Sleep(3000);` but it takes 3 seconds, and click the wrong button from command list, and right button from the button on form...

I tried control refresh and `Application.DoEvents` but nothing...

How can I do?

Comment: The typical way to automate UI actions is to use the [UI Automation APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview), not raw messages.

Comment: I can use:
    AutomationElement iColori = AutomationElement.FromHandle(colors.hWnd);

But there aren't buttons on this control... is only a {Bridge_View} with click in 5 coordinates.

How can simulate click with UI Automations ?

Comment: What about this strange way?

If i put setYellow() in a Timer or Event, it click red...

If i put it on a button click, it works correctly!

Why? :(